# Can we use delete on the reference (not the pointer) in a range-for loop?

Tags: c++

I am using an object factory with a function to create and register new objects :

```
Object * MyObjectFactory::createNewObject()
{
   Object * my_object = new Object();
   m_vector_of_objects.push_back(my_object);

   return my_object;
}
```

I am now writing the delete operator, where I just loop through the vector and delete all the objects, and I am wondering if there is a difference between :

```
MyObjectFactory::~MyObjectFactory()
{
   // Destroy memory allocated objects
   for (auto * my_object : m_vector_of_objects)
   {
      delete(my_object);
   }
}
```

and

```
MyObjectFactory::~MyObjectFactory()
{
   // Destroy memory allocated objects
   for (auto &my_object : m_vector_of_objects)
   {
      delete(my_object);
   }
}
```

Is it actually de-allocating memory in both case ?

Comment: There's no need for a manual `delete` in this code. Use `unique_ptr` instead.

Comment: Use a `std::unique_ptr`/`std::shared_ptr` in the vector.  Then all you need to do is let the vector go out of scope or call `clear` on it to delete all of the elements.  let [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) work for you.

Comment: @jwismar It's a reference to a pointer, so it is a pointer and delete-able.

Comment: To answer the question, no there is not an effective difference.   In the first, `my_object` is a pointer, with value that is equal to an element of `m_vector_of_objects`.  In the second, `my_object` is a reference to an element of `m_vector_of_objects`, so is a reference to a pointer.    In both cases, `delete (my_object)` or `delete my_object` have the same effect.   If the pointers in `m_vector_of_objects` are all assigned the result of a `new` expression (as in `MyObjectFactory::createNewObject()`, the dynamically allocated object will be released.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz using `std::unique_ptr` probably is not possible for code shown (pointer is stored and returned), looks like OP needs `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz About smart pointers, the factory has actually very little chance of being deleted, I was just doing it to avoid memory leak when unit-testing (where every test is creating is own factory). I may be wrong, but I feel like smart pointers will add unnecessary complexity in that case.

Comment: @4nti7rust smart pointers would remove unnecessary complexity, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it actually de-allocating memory in both case ?

Yes. There is no difference between deleting a copy of a pointer and deleting a the same pointer through a reference. Latter introduces a redundant layer of indirection (which is probably optimised away).

P.S. Owning bare pointers are a bad design. Prefer smart pointers and consider whether `Object`s need separate storage in the first place.

Comment: Might want to check the wording.   It is not deleting a reference.  It is applying the `delete` expression to the value of the referenced pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. About smart pointers, the factory as actually very little chance of being deleted, I was just doing it to avoid memory leak when unit-testing (where every test is creating is own factory). I may be wrong, but I feel like smart pointers will add unnecessary complexity.

Comment: @Peter It is a delete expression. The operand is an id expression that names a reference variable. It is a reference to a pointer. I don't see a problem with the wording.

Comment: @eerorika - it is an expression that names a reference variable.   But the `delete` expression does not act on the reference.   It acts on the pointer that the reference (um) references.

Comment: @Peter I changed the wording.

Comment: @eeronika - if the constructor of `Object` throws, the object is not leaked, because it was never created.   And the `push_back()` function will never be called.

Comment: @Peter I meant if `push_back` throws. The copies of the pointers of course can't throw - I wasn't thinking clearly. `push_back` can still throw if it fails to allocate, but in that case the program probably has no chance of recovering, so a leak is the least of ones' worries.